# Make WRAPPED text only as wide as its container div

Tags: html, css

The code snippet pretty much explains the issue. If I want to make a div only take as much space as its text, how can I do it if the text has wrapped into a new line???

[image]

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
}

.text-container-bad, .text-container-good {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="text-container-good">
    Shorter text that doesn't wrap and the container only takes as much space as the text
  </div>
  <div class="text-container-bad">
    This is a longer text that wraps and the container takes more horizontal space thaaaaaaaaaaaan its text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove display: inline-block: Inline-block elements will not wrap to the next line. Instead, use the default display: block.

Use max-width: fit-content;: This CSS property allows the element to expand as wide as its content, but not wider than the available space.

Comment: `fit-content` doesn't do what is trying to be done here. The goal is that the element is only as wide as the wrapped text, but that isn't really how CSS works. I'm not sure that there is a way to do that without JS. Everything in CSS is a box and the content wraps in the box. The box is the width that it is because it's taking up 100% of the space that it can. It's only wrapping because the text won't fit, but it still has to take up the full space.

Comment: you cannot do this

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

There's not an easy solution to this with CSS because of how CSS calculates the width of the divs.  It doesn't recalculate the width after rendering the line breaks.

If you you want to accomplish what the title of this post suggests, which is to make the wrapped text as wide as its container div, you can add word breaks:

```css
.text-container-bad, .text-container-good {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  word-break: break-all; /* Add this */
}
```

This will make it so 'tha...an' extends all the way to the end of the first line before breaking onto the second line.

Answer (score -3):

This problem doesn't have a straightforward CSS-only solution for all cases.

It's a little tricky due to the way CSS works with wrapping and block dimensions. Here's a workaround to get closer to the desired effect using CSS...

We can use `float: left` which makes the container only as wide as its content, even if the content wraps to multiple lines.

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text-container-bad,
.text-container-good {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="text-container-good">
    Shorter text that doesn't wrap and only takes as much space as the text
  </div>
  <div class="text-container-bad">
    This is a longer text that wraps and takes more horizontal space thaaaaaaaaaaaan its text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does seem to work. Just make sure you `clear: both;` on the following element. Otherwise you might get some unintended consequences.

Comment: If I set the container to a width of 500px it seems to fail